# Script that runs at login doesn't use internet

Tags: python, bash, macos

I have a bash script that has the launch agent

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
   <key>Label</key>
   <string>com.user.loginscript</string>
   <key>ProgramArguments</key>
   <array><string>/Users/Documents/Untitled.bash</string></array>
   <key>RunAtLoad</key>
   <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

and the bash script runs a python script that connects to a server and downloads a file. However the when the login agent runs and the bash script runs, the python script will not connect to the server to download the file. How can I fix this. (I am also on my mac)

Comment: Can you show us the code from the shell script and Python script—or, rather, a [mcve] that reproduces the problem? Do you have any kind of logging to tell you—and us—where things are going wrong (shell script not running, Python script not running, Python script getting an exception you weren't expecting, Python script getting an exception that you handle with `try:` and then throw away, …), or are we reduced to guessing wildly?

Comment: You are missing a `Program` key to tell it the name of your script.... https://medium.com/@fahimhossain_16989/adding-startup-scripts-to-launch-daemon-on-mac-os-x-sierra-10-12-6-7e0318c74de1